# A save-as-draft feature (maybe privilege for users with 500 points)?

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions

Many times, I wish I can save a question I'm typing up as a draft, so that I may revisit it. I mean, I want to sip coffee and walk and then sit down again in the library rather than my bed (I use different locales, because I realize that it currently would cache your page if you use the same computer).

It would be *so* convenient to have a "Save" option. Then I may work on 2 or 3 questions and fix one, then go to the other. Here a picture:

[image]

A little bit "heavy"? Well, perhaps, but that is why I think we only give the privilege for users with 500 points.

Comment: This already exists in a limited form, start asking a question then navigate away and then start a new question, do you mean something different?

Comment: This already exists, and to my knowledge, it's not a privilege at all; everyone has access to it.

Comment: @enderland - Yes, hmm however I can see what I like it is too complex. I would like "desktop application" powers - i.e I can save as if I'm in MS word. But alas, it is not practical for internet I think

Comment: @Servy - I'm dreaming of having something like full MS Word save feature. Or Gmail saving ability. to work on multiple questions perhaps. But I see now it is too broad of an idea and we need something more incremental

Comment: @Coffee Then save a copy of your question externally, if you need all of that functionality, and copy/paste it into the browser when you're done.

Comment: I came here to write the same question.   And discovered, like Coffee, that it already exists :)    So it's good that this question is here telling us that....  I edited the question with the intent of making it clear that it has the answer "can we have this feature": it's not especially important whether it requires rep.

Comment: Then precompose your question in your favorite text/code editor, save it locally, wander around or have whatever beverage you enjoy at your leisure, and post it here whenever you're happy with it. We don't force you to post it without being ready to do so. You want *desktop application powers*? Use a desktop application. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an automatic feature that works for everyone regardless of reputation.  As you are writing a question or answer, it automatically saves drafts so that you do not lose everything you have written.  You will notice that it saves when it has a "discard" button and a "draft saved" message, which I encountered while writing this answer:

[image: Auto Save Picture]

Once you come back to that question, it will remember that you were working on it and will only forgot it if you press the "discard" button.

Comment: Thank you, well I was thinking about something more "permanent" , however I can see the current model is sufficient